# Full Calendar with modal bootstrap ajax call renderevent

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

I am currently using a jquery loop and render all new events from ajax call

eg.

```
$.each(event, function(i,v){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', something...);
});
```

Theres no error outputs and was able to check that the events were put in the calendar. But only when I either change view/ change month

First time i open the calendar theres no output, after i click next and back you will see the events.

Big note: I am using bootstrap modal, so the fullcalendar is inside bootstrap modal box. I am thinking im having a problem with this

How do i render events that i dont need to change view / change month

I have tried adding these lines in the loop yet still no success, still need to change month

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
$("#calender").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```

Comment: "so the fullcalendar is inside fullcalendar" .. What do you want to say there ?

Comment: Sorry i just edited. its inside bootstrap modal box*

Comment: provide a fiddle if possible

Comment: figured it out

$('#calendarModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
     });

Answer (score 0):

figured it out

```
 $('#calendarModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { 
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' ); 
});
```

Need to recall this inside ajax success